# Convert date format 01-Feb-17 to 01-FEB-17

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

In Oracle database the date format was saved as `01-FEB-17`, I cant retrieve data by select statement when date format  `01-Feb-17`, the different between (**Feb** and **FEB**), How i can convert the format

Comment: Please post your code, your SQL query, and your table structure.  As well as the error you are getting.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
string smDate = YourDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yy").ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 1):

In *general case* you can create a custom format:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo oracleFormat = 
   (DateTimeFormatInfo) (CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.Clone());

// Put any months' abbreviations you want
oracleFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { 
   "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", 
   "APR", "MAY", "JUN", 
   "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", 
   "OCT", "NOV", "DEC", "" };
```

And then use it:

```
string oracleDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy", oracleFormat);
```